# How to Sql Join on one table contains same values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

```
P_Id    Catid   Score   ArtId   PostId  PhaseId UserId  Deleted ModDate
26      1       20      57      5       18      8       0       2014-03-29
27      2       18      57      5       18      8       0       2014-03-29
28      3       7       57      5       18      8       0       2014-03-29
29      4       5       57      5       18      8       0       2014-03-29
30      5       20      57      5       18      8       0       2014-03-29
31      1       12      57      1       18      9       0       2014-03-29
32      2       15      57      1       18      9       0       2014-03-29
33      3       15      57      1       18      9       0       2014-03-29
34      4       15      57      1       18      9       0       2014-03-29
35      5       19      57      1       18      9       0       2014-03-29
```

I want result like this...

```
Catid            Judge1       Judge2  
1                   20          12
2                   18          15
3                    7          15
4                    5          15
5                   20          19
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any joins to do this, it can be accomplished using `CASE`statements and aggregate functions.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae64d/3)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([P_Id] int, [Catid] int, [Score] int, [ArtId] int, [PostId] int, [PhaseId] int, [UserId] int, [Deleted] int, [ModDate] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([P_Id], [Catid], [Score], [ArtId], [PostId], [PhaseId], [UserId], [Deleted], [ModDate])
VALUES
    (26, 1, 20, 57, 5, 18, 8, 0, '2014-03-29'),
    (27, 2, 18, 57, 5, 18, 8, 0, '2014-03-29'),
    (28, 3, 7, 57, 5, 18, 8, 0, '2014-03-29'),
    (29, 4, 5, 57, 5, 18, 8, 0, '2014-03-29'),
    (30, 5, 20, 57, 5, 18, 8, 0, '2014-03-29'),
    (31, 1, 12, 57, 1, 18, 9, 0, '2014-03-29'),
    (32, 2, 15, 57, 1, 18, 9, 0, '2014-03-29'),
    (33, 3, 15, 57, 1, 18, 9, 0, '2014-03-29'),
    (34, 4, 15, 57, 1, 18, 9, 0, '2014-03-29'),
    (35, 5, 19, 57, 1, 18, 9, 0, '2014-03-29')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  Catid,
  SUM(CASE WHEN userid = 8 THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS Judge1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN userid = 9 THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS Judge2
FROM table1
GROUP BY catid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae64d/3/0)**:

```
| CATID | JUDGE1 | JUDGE2 |
|-------|--------|--------|
|     1 |     20 |     12 |
|     2 |     18 |     15 |
|     3 |      7 |     15 |
|     4 |      5 |     15 |
|     5 |     20 |     19 |
```

Comment: Thanks this is run... but when judges are multiple then what will be the result??? means when we don't know the how much judges are on the stage then what we do??? thank in advance...

Comment: @user3487809 Since the values are hard coded you would have to add additional case statements for the other judges. If you need a dynamic solution you need some way of mapping userid to judge#, maybe a lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.catid,a.score,b.score from
(select * from Table1 where userid = 8) a inner join 
(select * from Table1 where userid = 9) b on a.Catid = b.Catid
```